# git log: missing newline at end of output

Tags: git, shell

I have a directory containing many git repos.

I want to search for commits containing "foo" in the git repos with `git log -G foo`.

This does not work:

```
for repo in *; do (cd $repo; git log -G request --pretty=format:"%ad %h in $repo by %an, %s" --date=iso --since=2022-05-01) ; done | sort -r
```

For some reason some lines are glued together ("xyz2022-06-30")

```
2022-04-29 17:02:03 +0200 b0b9b30b in bar by Thomas, xyz2022-06-30 14:25:09 +0200 47dbcb3 in applicant_management by dennis, Implement renames and relocations of columns in InstitutionSlotAdmin
```

The output of `git log` seems to be missing a newline at the end.

How to fix this one-liner?

Comment: Search for `tformat` in [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log); this will explain all.

Answer (score 1):

tested on my machine (bash on Ubuntu, using `git 2.35.0`) I see the same issue :

when the output of `git log ...` is piped, there is no trailing `\n` (seen using `git log ... | hd`)

A quick (and hacky) fix : add an empty `echo` at the end of your loop :

```
for repo in *; do (cd $repo; \
   git log -G request --pretty=format:"%ad %h in $repo by %an, %s" \
     --date=iso --since=2022-05-01; \
   echo); done | sort -r
#   ^
#  here
```

Comment: note : I wrapped the one liner over 4 lines for readability, but you can technically still type on one single line ;)

Comment: Is the missing newline a bug or feature of git?

Comment: several commands detect if their output is a tty or not and change their output based on that (`ls` or `grep` or `git log` turn off their colors for example) I'd say this missing `\n` is a glitch, don't know if there is an ulterior motive

Comment: Or use `pretty=tformat:` (aka `--format=`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of LeGEC:

```
for repo in *; do (cd $repo; \
   git log -G request --pretty="%ad %h in $repo by %an, %s" \
     --date=iso --since=2022-05-01); done | sort -r
```